How to use laravel purity filter i am getting an error
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        
        $Services = ServiceRequest::filter()->paginate(2);
        

        return view('backend.leads.lead-index',['Services' => $Services]);
    }

/admin/leads-management?filters:[status][$en]=New   (i was expecting this)
/admin/leads-management?status=New   (but getting this in url)

please clarify more and fix your code , what is the error exactly what sould it do ??

Show your route file.Have you imported this use Abbasudo\Purity\Traits\Filterable; inside your model ?
